# Practical advise for CMS

Tags: php, optimization, mysql

I'm working on a CMS system. The basis is pretty much done but before going any further I would like to know if there are things I really should change in the way I code things.

I am pretty sure there will be a few things that could be done different, since I pretty much started with this project without any actual prior experience in writing my own php/sql projects.

I'd like to know if there are some things I shouldn't change but most of all things I should change or be cautious of in the way I do things.

I will be including the files that mainly contain functions.
There are some more files involved but these are the most important ones.

You can also view an example of the site at: http://www.tulexi.net/tulexi_dev/

Functions.m - Used for interfaces

```
<?php
function show_content($id,$category){
 global $con;
 if($category == 'news'){
 $sql = "SELECT n.id, n.title, n.author, n.content, n.date, u.username
   FROM news AS n, users AS u
   WHERE n.author = u.id && n.id = :id";
 $q = $con->prepare($sql);
 $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $q->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $q->execute();

 foreach($q->fetchAll() as $news){
  $author_id = (int)$news['author'];
  $author = $news['username'];
  $title = $news['title'];
  $content = $news['content'];
  $date = date('d-M-Y / H:i', strtotime($news['date']));
  $edit_button = '';
  $delete_button = '';
  if(isset($_SESSION['userid']) && $_SESSION['userid'] == $author_id && session_level(2) || session_level(3)){
   $edit_button = '<a href="?page=edit_news&id='.$id.'"><img align="right" src="./images/edit.png"></a>';
   $delete_button = '<a href="./process.php?action=delete_news&id='.$id.'" class="confirm"><img align="right" src="./images/delete.png"></a>';
  }
  $news = '<div class="wrapper pad_bot2">
  <figure class="left marg_right1 user_image"><img src="./user_images/'.$author_id.'.jpg" alt=""></figure>
  <div class="title">'.$title.$delete_button.$edit_button.'</div>
  <div class="date">From: '.$author.' On: '.$date.'</div>
  <p>'.bbcode($content).'</p>
  </div>';
  echo $news;
  }
 }
}
function list_news($max) {
 global $con;

 //Count amount of rows currently in DB.
 $count = $con->query("SELECT id FROM news")->RowCount();

 if(!isset($_GET['nr'])||$_GET['nr']<1){
  $page= 1;
 }else{
  $page = $_GET['nr'];
 }
 $start = ($page-1)*$max;
 $prev = http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array('nr'=>$page-1)),'&');
 if($start <= $count){
  $next = http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array('nr'=>$page+0)),'&');
 } else {
  $next = http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array('nr'=>$page+1)),'&');
 }


 $sql = "SELECT n.id, n.title, n.author, n.content, n.date, u.username
   FROM news AS n, users AS u
   WHERE n.author = u.id
   ORDER BY n.date Desc
   LIMIT :start, :max";
 $q = $con->prepare($sql);
 $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $q->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $q->bindParam(':max', $max, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $q->execute();

 echo '<div class="paging"><a href="?'.$prev.'">&lt;Newer</a> | <a href="?'.$next.'">Older&gt;</a></div>'; 
 foreach($q->fetchAll() as $news){
  $id = $news['id'];
  $author_id = (int)$news['author'];
  $author = $news['username'];
  $title = '<a href="?p=home&id='.$id.'">'.$news['title'].'</a>';
  $content = $news['content'];
  $date = date('d-M-Y / H:i', strtotime($news['date']));
  $edit_button = '';
  $delete_button = '';
  if(isset($_SESSION['userid']) && $_SESSION['userid'] == $author_id && session_level(2) || session_level(3)){
   $edit_button = '<a href="?page=edit_news&id='.$id.'"><img align="right" src="./images/edit.png"></a>';
   $delete_button = '<a href="./process.php?action=delete_news&id='.$id.'" class="confirm"><img align="right" src="./images/delete.png"></a>';
  }
  $news = '<div class="wrapper pad_bot2">
  <figure class="left marg_right1 user_image"><img src="./user_images/'.$author_id.'.jpg" alt=""></figure>
  <div class="title">'.$title.$delete_button.$edit_button.'</div>
  <div class="date">From: '.$author.' On: '.$date.'</div>
  <p>'.bbcode(truncate($content,200)).'</p>
  </div>';
  echo $news;
 }
}
function truncate($text,$max){
 if(strlen($text) > $max+3){
  return substr($text,0,$max).'[ellipsis]';
 } else {
  return $text;
 }
}
function categories_dropdown(){
 global $con;
  $sql = "SELECT id, name
   FROM categories
   ORDER BY name";
 $q = $con->query($sql);
 $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $q->execute();

 foreach($q->fetchAll() as $categorie){
  echo '<option value="'.$categorie['id'].'" class="select">'.$categorie['name'].'</option>'; 
 }
}
function profile_edit($userid){
 if(session_level(3) || $userid == $_SESSION['userid']){
  global $con;

  $sql = ("SELECT mail
    FROM users
    WHERE id = :id");
  $q = $con->prepare($sql);
  $q->bindParam(':id', $userid);
  $q->execute();

  $row = $q->fetch();

  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $mail = $row['mail'];
  echo '<div id="usercp">Welcome to your control panel '.$username.', here you can add or change settings for your account.<br>
   <br>
   Only fill in a field if it has to be changed.';

  $form = '<form method="post" action="./process.php?action=edit_userinfo">
  <figure class="user_image"><img src="./user_images/'.$userid.'.jpg"></figure>
  <div class="avatar">Avatar: <input name="user_image" type="file" />
  <div class="note">.jpg files only. Required size is 100*100</div></div>
  <div class="password">New Password: <input type="password" name="password" class="input" /></div>
  <div class="password">Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="password2" class="input" /></div>
  <div class="mail">E-Mail adres: <input type="text" name="mail" class="input" value="'.$mail.'"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="'.$userid.'">
  <input type="hidden" name="submit">
  <input type="submit" value="Apply Changes">
  </form>';
  echo $form.'</div>';
  if(isset($_GET['s'])){
   echo '<br>User info has been changed.';
  }
 }  else {
  echo 'You are not authorized to vieuw this page.';
  die();
 }
}
?>
```

Functions.db - Used to add or change database information

```
<?php
function addnews($title,$content,$date,$author){
 global $con;

 $sql = "INSERT INTO news
   (title,
    content,
    date,
    author) VALUES
   (:title,
    :content,
    :date,
    :author)";
 $q = $con->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array(':title'=>$title,
       ':content'=>$content,
       ':date'=>$date,
       ':author'=>$author));
}

function editnews($title,$content,$date,$id){
 global $con;

 $sql = "UPDATE news
   SET title = :title,
    content = :content,
    edit_date = :date
   WHERE id = :id";
 $q = $con->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array(':title'=>$title,
       ':content'=>$content,
       ':date'=>$date,
       ':id'=>$id));
}

function delete_news($id){
 global $con;

 $sql = "SELECT author
   FROM news
   WHERE id = :id";
 $q = $con->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
 $row = $q->Fetch();

 if($_SESSION['userid'] !== $row['author'] && !session_level(3)){
  header('Location: ./');
  die;
 }
 $sql = "DELETE FROM news
   WHERE id = :id";
 $q = $con->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
}
function addcontent($title,$content,$date,$author,$category){
 global $con;

 $sql = "INSERT INTO content
   (name,
    content,
    date,
    author,
    category) VALUES
   (:name,
    :content,
    :date,
    :author,
    :category)";
 $q = $con->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array(':name'=>$title,
       ':content'=>$content,
       ':date'=>$date,
       ':author'=>$author,
       ':category'=>$category));
}
function edit_userpassword($password, $salt, $userid){
 global $con;

 if($userid !== $_SESSION['userid'] && !session(3)){
  echo 'You do not have permission to execute this action. <a href="./">Return to homepage</a>';
  die();
 } else {
 $sql = "UPDATE users
   SET password = :password,
    salt = :salt
   WHERE id = :id";
 $q = $con->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array(':password'=>$password,
       ':salt'=>$salt,
       ':id'=>$userid)); 
 }
}
function edit_usermail($mail, $userid){
 global $con;

 if($userid !== $_SESSION['userid'] && !session(3)){
  echo 'You do not have permission to execute this action. <a href="./">Return to homepage</a>';
  die();
 } else {
 $sql = "UPDATE users
   SET mail = :mail
   WHERE id = :id";
 $q = $con->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array(':mail'=>$mail,
       ':id'=>$userid)); 
 } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well for starters you can start learning object oriented programming and why the procedural approach you've taken will be 100% impossible to maintain and further develop. You can also stop using global variables (which the use of objects will help you avoid).

Unfortunately I can't get more specific than that since object oriented programming is very large topic. And once you've learned how to code objects in PHP, it's a whole other topic to learn good software architecture principles for something as complex as a CMS.

So my advice:

- Read up on what object oriented programming is, and why it's necessary
- Follow basic tutorials for working with PHP's OOP syntax
- Read more advanced tutorials on the principles behind good OOP concepts
- Read even more advanced tutorials on good software architecture concepts to keep your code modular, reusable, readable, and extensible

Sorry for not providing concrete links, but there are so many results in Google that there's no point.